Revenue not showing for custom purchase event
I have made a new custom event called 'sales_from_chat' and marked it as a key event. I am firing this event instead of 'purchase' if purchase is being made through chat bot on the website. Following is the gtag code.
gtag("event", "sales_from_chat", { "transaction_id":11216613, "value":111.33, "tax":6.4, "shipping":24.95, "currency":"USD", "items":[ { "item_id":"507", "item_name":"One Dozen Red Roses", "currency":"USD", "price":"67.99", "quantity":"1", "item_variant":"22075" }, { "item_id":"1157", "item_name":"ball-lx", "currency":"USD", "price":"2.00", "quantity":"1", "item_variant":"Addon" } ], "send_to":"analytics" });
The problem is Google Analytics showing event counts but not displaying the revenue as it is showing for the purchase event. How can I fix this.
I have debugged through Google Tag Assistant, all the parameters are same as 'purchase' event. But revenue is not being shown in the reports.
